# Jenkins user cannot copy files to Apache /var/www folder - all permissions appropriate

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, jenkins

Jenkins is installed on Ubuntu 18.04 and is running successfully.

As part of our project build process, we need to copy built files to a specific folder under `/var/www/html` (Apache folder). Our build / Execute shell:

```
npm install
ng build --prod
cp -R /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/kagi-core/dist/core/* /var/www/html/kagi-core/
```

But jenkins build fails at the final copy command with the following errors:

```
23:18:10 + cp -R /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/kagi-core/dist/core/3rdpartylicenses.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/kagi-core/dist/core/assets ...
23:18:10 cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/html/kagi-core/3rdpartylicenses.txt': Permission denied
...
...
```

Here's what we did/tried so far:

1. Added "jenkins" user to root and ubuntu groups.

   ```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-215:/var/www/html$ groups jenkins
    jenkins : jenkins root ubuntu
   ```
2. Changed permissions on /var/www/html/kagi-core folders to "jenkins" user

   ```
    drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu jenkins 4096 Sep 17 21:36 www
    ..
    drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu jenkins 4096 Sep 18 21:04 html
    ..
    drwxrwxrwx 4 ubuntu jenkins  4096 Sep 18 21:18 kagi-core
   ```

What are we missing? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

While trying to fix this, found the solution. Adding here for reference:

On observing carefully, the permissions to `/var/www` folders, they are as

`drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu jenkins 4096 Sep 17 21:36 www`

but instead they should be the other way around (allow "jenkins" user to the default group):

`drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins ubuntu 4096 Sep 17 21:36 www`

Also we reset the group to default `root`

So the command that solved the issue was

```
cd /var
sudo chown -R jenkins:root www/
```

After this, jenkins builds were successful (able to copy to the `/var/www/html` folder).